# error creating workspace/mavros error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I have been using the install guide  from [erle robotics](http://erlerobotics.com/docs/Simulation/Configuring_your_environment.html) and when i try to exectute the following commands (last 3 at the bottom of the guide,after installing gazebo) it works fine until the last one: `catkin_make`

```
cd ~/simulation/ros_catkin_ws    
source devel/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

It shows an error message

```
  CMake Error at mavros/libmavconn/cmake/Modules/MavrosMavlink.cmake:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findmavlink.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "mavlink", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mavlink" with any
  of the following names:

    mavlinkConfig.cmake
    mavlink-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "mavlink" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "mavlink_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "mavlink" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mavros/libmavconn/CMakeLists.txt:16 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cyberpunk/simulation/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cyberpunk/simulation/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

## #1 EDIT 25/5

I followed the mavros install instructions [install instructions](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#installation) (as proposed at one answer) and at step #5 `catkin build` it prints out this error message

```
Errors     << test_mavros:cmake /home/cyberpunk/catkin_ws/logs/test_mavros/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "control_toolbox"
  with any of the following names:

    control_toolboxConfig.cmake
    control_toolbox-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "control_toolbox" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "control_toolbox_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "control_toolbox" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "control_toolbox"
  with any of the following names:

    control_toolboxConfig.cmake
    control_toolbox-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "control_toolbox" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "control_toolbox_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "control_toolbox" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


cd /home/cyberpunk/catkin_ws/build/test_mavros; catkin build --get-env test_mavros | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/cyberpunk/catkin_ws/src/mavros/test_mavros --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/cyberpunk/catkin_ws/devel/.private/test_mavros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/cyberpunk/catkin_ws/install; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << test_mavros:cmake                    [ Exited with code 1 ]      
Failed    <<< test_mavros                          [ 1.0 seconds ]             
[build] Summary: 6 of 7 packages succeeded.                                    
[build]   Ignored:   None.                                                     
[build]   Warnings:  1 packages succeeded with warnings.                       
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                     
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                        
[build] Runtime: 3 minutes and 4.3 seconds total.                              
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234929/error-creating-workspace/mavros-error/) by [Evans](https://answers.ros.org/users/26867/evans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-22**:
There is probably more error output that comes with that. Could you add that to your question (please *edit* it)?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-24**:
What I suggest is to delete the folder `ros_catkin_ws` and create it , build it again. And if you have the same error report it again here with the steps you follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your error is because `catkin_make` can't find [mavlink](https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink) when trying to build the `mavros` ROS package. From your question, it's not clear exactly which instructions you are trying to follow, but if you are following instructions it's possible they are outdated. Check out the [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#installation) on the mavros GitHub page. They include steps for getting mavlink. Note that the current version of the instructions use [catkin tools](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for building the workspace. That is not necessary. You could use vanilla `catkin` instead, but you'll likely have to use `catkin_make_isolated` instead of `catkin_make` because mavlink is not a ROS package.

**EDIT**

After the latest edit from OP the error has changed to a missing dependency on the `control_toolbox` package when building the `test_mavros` package. Either install this package from `apt-get` (it's available on Indigo) or add it to the workspace and build it from source. Note that the originally linked instructions include the following line

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

which should automatically install `ros-indigo-control-toolbox` using apt-get. It appears this package is properly listed in the test_mavros package.xml and CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1